# Cant load detailViewController from tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitableview

I have a table view loading a sqldata file that displays labels and a image in the
cells. I wish to load th image and other data into the next vc but cant seem to even get
a log to pull back the file time so have no chance of pushing it over. It is all being
done programatically so finding it a little harder.  All help appreciated!!!

> //Table view
>
> ```
>    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath >*)indexPath {
>
>        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
>
>        ATPictureViewController *newView = [[ATPictureViewController alloc] init];
>        
>        newView.mainImageView.image=[tableView >cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image ;
>        
>        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
>        
>       // NSLog(@"Log33 %@",);
>    }
>
>    @end
> ```

I thought this was it

newView.mainImageView.image=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image;

but brings me nothing

> ```
>     //vc.h
>    
>    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
>    
>    @interface ATPictureViewController : UIViewController{
>        
>        UIImageView *mainImage;
>    }
>    
>    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *mainImageView;
>    
>    @end
> ```

not sure if i call something here

> ```
>    //vc.m
>    
>    - (void)viewDidLoad
>    {
>        [super viewDidLoad];
>        
>        self.mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200,    200)];
>        [self.view addSubview:self.mainImageView];
>        
>        self.mainImageView.image = ???????????
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem, maybe two. First, you can't set the image of mainImageView in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, because ATPictureViewController's view hasn't been loaded at that point, and its mainImageView property will be nil. Instead, you should create a UIImage property in ATPictureViewController, and assign the value of that to [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You can then set the image of mainImageView in ATPictureViewController's viewDidLoad method.

Another possible problem is  using alloc init to instantiate newView. Depending on where you made your view for that controller, you'll probably get a blank view. You should probably use initWithNibName:bundle: if you made you view in a xib, or instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: if you made it in a storyboard.